# Read file line by line and store lines in array of strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, line, readfile, readlines

I have problem reading a file in c and storing in array of strings

```
char **aLineToMatch;
FILE *file2; 
int bufferLength = 255;
char buffer[bufferLength];
int i;

char *testFiles[] = { "L_2005149PL.01002201.xml.html",
                       "L_2007319PL.01000101.xml.html",
                       NULL};

char *testStrings[] = { "First",
                         "Second",
                         "Third.",
                          NULL};


file = fopen(testFiles[0], "r"); // loop will come later, thats not the problem

while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, file2) != NULL) {
 printf("%s\n", buffer);
 // here should be adding to array of strings (testStrings declared above)
} 
 fclose(file);
}
```

and then I do some checks, some prints etc.

```
for(aLineToMatch=testStrings; *aLineToMatch != NULL; aLineToMatch++) {
    printf("String: %s\n", *aLineToMatch);
```

How to properly change the values of `*testFiles[]` to include valid values read from file and add NULL at the end?

Comment: `char *testFiles[] = ` allocates an array of pointers that is exactly as long as the initialiser - in your case four.  So you can't add things to that array because you can't resize it.  Instead, you need to use malloc to create an array of pointers so that when you fill it up you can realloc it.  That's easy enough.  What do you want to do if the line in the file is longer than bufferLength ? Right now you are truncating it but that might noit be the thing you want to do.

Comment: Ok, as I said in my last comment, you probably want to read the whole line into one array item - fgets stops when it gets to bufferLength, and then the rest of the string ends up in the next array item.  To stop that you need to realloc the length of the strings as well as the length of the array: https://onlinegdb.com/rkiGHH98O

Answer (score 3):

I think the key issue here is that in C you must manage your own memory, and you need to know the difference between the different types of storage available in C.

Simply put, there's:

1. Stack
2. Heap
3. Static

Here's some relevant links with more detail about this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

https://craftofcoding.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/memory-in-c-the-stack-the-heap-and-static/

In higher-level languages everything is on the heap anyway so you can pretty much manipulate it however you please.
However, bog-standard arrays and strings in C have static storage of a fixed size.

The rest of this answer is in the code comments below.

I've modified your code and tried to give explanations and context as to why it is needed.

```
// @Compile gcc read_line_by_line.c && ./a.out
// @Compile gcc read_line_by_line.c && valgrind ./a.out
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// When declaring an array, the size of the array must be a compile-time constant
// i.e. it cannot be a dynamic variable like this: int n = 3; int numbers[n];
#define BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES 255

// Uses static program storage, size is fixed at time of compilation
char *files[] = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt"}; // The size of this symbol is (sizeof(char*) * 2)
// Hence this line of code is valid even outside the body of a function
// because it doesn't actually execute,
// it just declares some memory that the compiler is supposed to provision in the resulting binary executable

// Divide the total size, by the size of an element, to calculate the number of elements
const int num_files = sizeof(files) / sizeof(files[0]);

int main() {
  printf("Program start\n\n");

  printf("There are %d files to read.\n", num_files);

  // These lines are in the body of a function and they execute at runtime
  // This means we are now allocating memory 'on-the-fly' at runtime
  int num_lines = 3;
  char **lines = malloc(sizeof(lines[0]) * num_lines);

  // lines[0] = "First"; // This would assign a pointer to some static storage containing the bytes { 'F', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '\0' }
  lines[0] = strdup("First");  // Use strdup() instead to allocate a copy of the string on the heap
  lines[1] = strdup("Second"); // This is so that we don't end up with a mixture of strings
  lines[2] = strdup("Third");  // with different kinds of storage in the same array
  // because only the heap strings can be free()'d
  // and trying to free() static strings is an error
  // but you won't be able to tell them apart,
  // they will all just look like pointers
  // and you won't know which ones are safe to free()

  printf("There are %d lines in the array.\n", num_lines);

  // Reading the files this way only works for lines shorter than 255 characters
  /*
  printf("\nReading file...\n");
  FILE *fp = fopen(files[0], "r");
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES];
  while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    // Resize the array we allocated on the heap
    void *ptr = realloc(lines, (num_lines + 1) * sizeof(lines[0]));
    // Note that this can fail if there isn't enough free memory available
    // This is also a comparatively expensive operation
    // so you wouldn't typically do a resize for every single line
    // Normally you would allocate extra space, wait for it to run out, then reallocate
    // Either growing by a fixed size, or even doubling the size, each time it gets full

    // Check if the allocation was successful
    if (ptr == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory at %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      assert(false);
    }
    // Overwrite `lines` with the pointer to the new memory region only if realloc() was successful
    lines = ptr;

    // We cannot simply lines[num_lines] = buffer
    // because we will end up with an array full of pointers
    // that are all pointing to `buffer`
    // and in the next iteration of the loop
    // we will overwrite the contents of `buffer`
    // so all appended strings will be the same: the last line of the file

    // So we strdup() to allocate a copy on the heap
    // we must remember to free() this later
    lines[num_lines] = strdup(buffer);

    // Keep track of the size of the array
    num_lines++;
  }
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Done.\n");
  */

  // I would recommend reading the file this way instead
  ///*
  printf("\nReading file...\n");
  FILE *fp = fopen(files[0], "r");
  char *new_line = NULL; // This string is allocated for us by getline() and could be any length, we must free() it though afterwards
  size_t str_len = 0;    // This will store the length of the string (including null-terminator)
  ssize_t bytes_read; // This will store the bytes read from the file (excluding null-terminator), or -1 on error (i.e. end-of-file reached)
  while ((bytes_read = getline(&new_line, &str_len, fp)) != -1) {
    printf("%s\n", new_line);

    // Resize the array we allocated on the heap
    void *ptr = realloc(lines, (num_lines + 1) * sizeof(lines[0]));
    // Note that this can fail if there isn't enough free memory available
    // This is also a comparatively expensive operation
    // so you wouldn't typically do a resize for every single line
    // Normally you would allocate extra space, wait for it to run out, then reallocate
    // Either growing by a fixed size, or even doubling the size, each time it gets full

    // Check if the allocation was successful
    if (ptr == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory at %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      assert(false);
    }
    // Overwrite `lines` with the pointer to the new memory region only if realloc() was successful
    lines = ptr;

    // Allocate a copy on the heap
    // so that the array elements don't all point to the same buffer
    // we must remember to free() this later
    lines[num_lines] = strdup(new_line);

    // Keep track of the size of the array
    num_lines++;
  }
  free(new_line); // Free the buffer that was allocated by getline()
  fclose(fp);     // Close the file since we're done with it
  printf("Done.\n");
  //*/

  printf("\nThere are %d lines in the array:\n", num_lines);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
    printf("%d: \"%s\"\n", i, lines[i]);
  }

  // Here you can do what you need to with the data...

  // free() each string
  // We know they're all allocated on the heap
  // because we made copies of the statically allocated strings
  for (int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
    free(lines[i]);
  }

  // free() the array itself
  free(lines);

  printf("\nProgram end.\n");
  // At this point we should have free()'d everything that we allocated
  // If you run the program with Valgrind, you should get the magic words:
  // "All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible"
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add elements to an array, you have 3 options:

1. Determine the maximum number of elements at compile-time and create a correctly sized arrray
2. Determine the maximum number of elements at run-time and create a variable-length array (works only in C99 and later)
3. Dynamically allocate the array and expand it as needed

Option 1 doesn't work here because it is impossible to know at compile-time how many lines your file will have.

Option 2 would imply that you first find the number of lines, which means to iterate the file twice. It also means that when you return from the function that reads the file, the array is automatically deallocated.

Option 3 is the best. Here is an example:

```
char **aLineToMatch;
FILE *file2; 
int bufferLength = 255;
char buffer[bufferLength];
int i = 0;

char *testFiles[] = { "L_2005149PL.01002201.xml.html",
                       "L_2007319PL.01000101.xml.html",
                       NULL};

char (*testStrings)[bufferLength] = NULL; //pointer to an array of strings

//you probably meant file2 here (or the normal file in the while condition)
file2 = fopen(testFiles[0], "r"); // loop will come later, thats not the problem

while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, file2) != NULL) {
 printf("%s\n", buffer);
 testStrings = realloc(testStrings, (i + 1) * sizeof testStrings[0]);
 strcpy(testStrings[i], buffer);
 i++;
} 
 fclose(file);
}
```